# DZNEmptyDataSet - Showing Activity Indicator on didTap Button

Tags: swift

I have below code for custom view

```
func customView(forEmptyDataSet scrollView: UIScrollView!) -> UIView! {

        if isRefreshing {

            let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: view.frame)            
            activityIndicator.center = view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white
            scrollView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

            return activityIndicator
        }

        return nil

    }
```

and this is didTap button method

```
func emptyDataSet(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, didTap button: UIButton) {

        isRefreshing = true
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        searchData()

    }
```

SearchData() is called from viewDidAppear() and  activity indicator shows fine.

However, on empty screen if i tap reload button,The code in customView method is executed and activityIndicator is returned but not displayed.

How to fix it?

Cheers, 
Ashish

Comment: Code is not sufficient to identify your problem. Can u add more.. like how do you stop activityIndicator and view did appear code?

Comment: Above two methods are part of DZNEmptyDataSet framework that need to be overridden. Framework doesn't  require activityIndicator to stop at least as shown in sample code. In viewDidAppear, i simply make call to database.